# Recreating Millikan's Photoelectric Experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-circuits, experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

I am designing a set-up to recreate Millikan’s Photoelectric [Experiment](https://www.mpoweruk.com/figs/Plancks-Constant.htm), which is similar to all the standard online [simulations](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations/photoelectric). I hope to achieve this without using a vacuum as it is very expensive to create a vacuum tube with two metal plates without purchasing new machines. Would there still be detectable stopping voltage without the noise/interference of the environment? Or is a voltage amplifier required before applying an EMF with a light of 300- 700nm?

Seond, I am not sure if this community is right for these questions, should it be posted to electrical engineering?

Answer (score 1):

The photoelectron will lose most of its energy in its first collision with a gas molecule. The mean free path in air is only ~68 nm, so you can't practically do this experiment without a good vacuum.

Perhaps you should try using a bit of antique technology: a vacuum phototube (not a photomultiplier). These consist of a photocathode and an anode in an evacuated glass bulb. I see various types for sale on the network. I don't know how well such a thing would work, though: they  use a small anode normally biased at a positive potential to collect the photoelectrons. With negative bias, I would expect little photocurrent from the low anode cross section even if the photoelectrons have the enewrgy to reach it.